# Triggers in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, audit, nhibernate-configuration

I'd like to know if is there something like a Trigger (of databases) in NHibernate that I can  use per entity ?

I'd like to make a history of each record, and with triggers I can compare the old value and new value of each property and generate a register of history.

I've heard about Audit in NHibernate, but it's for all entities, if there isn't another way...  how Can I separete a block per entity ?

Thanks

Comment: You are unlikely to get more answers if you never accept them.